# Devops pipeline not kicking off the logging because it's not triggering "dotnet appname.dll"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

we are using Devops to build and deploy a QA environment which I am fairly new to.

We have a .net core web app and the issue is the serilog logging which is configured in program.cs is not kickstarted when it gets deployed. This does work locally of course.

The pipeline seems to use the sln files but doesnt call "dotnet appname.dll" which is what actually starts the logging.

The logging starts if I run "dotnet appname.dll" in powershell but that is not connected to the app when its accessed in the browser from the outside if you get me.

Do I just need to add that command to this pipeline here?

[image]

The web app is also using IIS.

Comment: Azure pipelines is used for building your app, use either [classic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops) or [YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) to trigger a  release to deploy your app.

Comment: Well this pipeline is the release isnt it?

Comment: @LukePerrin `dotnet appname.dll` do you need to run this command on AWS EC2 server?

Comment: Yea, we have a batch file which is deleting some old stuff and doing an IIS start but that doesnt actually engage the myapp.dll does it. Its running within IIS on an AWS EC2 Server

Comment: If I run dotnet appname.dll manually then starts a new process and i get logs  but has nothing to do with the main web app on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was down to IIS not having permissions to write to the Serilog output file. All the azure devops stuff was a red herring.